# How to get number from file that is written

Tags: java, file

I am making an java program for college and I am stuck at one point, the exam says I need to extract information from an `txt` file that is already written. I need to get only the information from the end of the lines like password or something.

**DISCLAIMER:**

I know how to do it by using scanner and file. But it is not really clear how to extract only the information not the whole line.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;


public class Trip {
    
    private String password;
    private String placeOfDeparture;
    private String destination;
    private int durationInDays;
    private double wage;
    private double rentPrice;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String[] passwords;
    
    public Trip(String placeOfDeparture, String destination, int durationInDays, double wage,
            double rentPrice, String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.placeOfDeparture = placeOfDeparture;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.durationInDays = durationInDays;
        this.wage = wage;
        this.rentPrice = rentPrice;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        generateTripPassword();
    }

    
    public void generateTripPassword() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNumbers = rand.nextInt(100);
        String personInitials = "";
        String departureInitials = "";
        String destinationInitials = "";
        
        personInitials += firstName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        personInitials += lastName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        departureInitials += placeOfDeparture.substring(0, 2).toUpperCase();
        destinationInitials += destination.substring(0, 2).toUpperCase();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < passwords.length; i++) {
            if(passwords[i] == null) {
                passwords[i] = personInitials + departureInitials + destinationInitials + randomNumbers;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        this.password = personInitials + departureInitials + destinationInitials + randomNumbers;
    }
    
    public void getTripInformation() {
        System.out.println("Trip details: \n");
        System.out.println("Trip password: " + password);
        System.out.println("Passenger name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + ".");
        System.out.println("Duration in days: " + durationInDays + ".");
        System.out.println("Wage: " + wage + ".");
        System.out.println("Rent price is: " + rentPrice + ".");
    }
    
    public void writeTripInfo(String tripType) {
        File file = new File(this.password + ".txt");
        try {
            FileWriter trip = new FileWriter(file);
            trip.write("Trip details: ");
            trip.write("Trip password: " + password);
            trip.write("Passenger name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + ".");
            trip.write("Duration in days: " + durationInDays + ".");
            trip.write("Wage: " + wage + ".");
            trip.write("Rent price is: " + rentPrice + ".");
            trip.write("Type of the trip is: " + tripType);
            trip.close();
            System.out.println("File writing successfully completed! Name of yje file is: " + this.password + " . Enjoy.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occured while writing file.");
            System.out.println("Here is the error debug code: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the contents of the file? Is it the same file created in `writeTripInfo()`?

Comment: Yes, I mean that is the only method that writes something.

Comment: Can you modify that function? You have nothing separating the fields - like newline or tab.

Comment: What do you mean, I don't understand really. If you can modify the code so I can see what is meant.

Comment: Open the file in a text editor. All the info will be smooshed on one line. Adding newlines after each field will make it easier to parse.

Comment: Ok I did that, but how I get the password variable from the file, that's what I originally meant.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp and I thought [smooshed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smoosh) wasn't a real word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have put each part on its own line (and removed the '.' at the end), you can parse each line by splitting on ':'

```
public void readTripInfo(String path)
{
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        String line;
        // Read each line of file
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Split on ':'
            String [] parts = line.split(":");
            if (parts.length == 2) {
                // Save
                if (parts[0].equals("Trip password")) {
                    password = parts[1].trim();
                }
                else if (parts[0].equals("Passenger name")) {
                    String [] names = parts[1].trim().split(" ");
                    if (names.length == 2) {
                        firstName = names[0];
                        lastName = names[1];
                    }
                }
                else if (parts[0].equals("Duration in days")) {
                    durationInDays = Integer.parseInt(parts[1].trim());
                }
                // Continue for the rest
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```